# How do I create an instance of the NetworkInterfacesOperations?

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to access an Azure VM Scale Set via the Python SDK, to get a list of all the NICs inside it. To do that, I'm guessing I need to use the  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_09_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python), but I don't know what each parameter should be for the NetworkInterfacesOperations class

NetworkInterfacesOperations(client, config, serializer, deserializer)

Comment: Did see this? :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_09_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_network_v2017_09_01_operations_NetworkInterfacesOperations_list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces

Comment: so you are literally linking to the same page and asking if he saw it?

Comment: I think that every  parameter of that scripts has already been in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create directly an instance of this class, this class will be an attribute on the Network client.

Example on how to create a Network client:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/network

Some info about authentication:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate

Once you have a client, you can access VMSS NICs:

```
nics = client.network_interfaces.list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces(
    resource_group_name,
    virtual_machine_scale_set_name
)
```

List operations returns an [Iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) like subclass. In this case, content are [NetworkInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_09_01.models.networkinterface?view=azure-python) instance.

```
for nic in nics:
    do_something(nic)
```

All Iterators syntax are allowed (`next()`, list-comprehension, `list()`, etc.)